Nextflow : how to pass the process outputs varying size to a channel based an optional inputs
My workflow process the following optional inputs params.yaml

samples id,  alignment (aln) file OR
Sample id,  variants  (vcf) file OR
Sample id, both alignment (aln) file and variants (vcf) file.

How do I give the list of output files which are varying in size 2 output files (sample id + only vcf) or 5 output files (sample id + only aln) or 7 output files (sample id + vcf and aln) as a common input sets to a process ga4gh_metrics. Appreciate any help.
params.yaml
samples:
-
 biosample_id: NA12878 
 aln: /data/NA12878.bam
 vcf: /data/NA12878.hard-filtered.vcf.gz
-
 biosample_id: NA12877
 aln: /data/NA12877.bam
 vcf: /data/NA12877.hard-filtered.vcf.gz

OR

samples:
-
 biosample_id: NA12878 
 aln: /data/NA12878.bam
-
 biosample_id: NA12877
 aln: /data/NA12877.bam

OR

samples:
-
 biosample_id: NA12878 
 vcf: /data/NA12878.hard-filtered.vcf.gz
-
 biosample_id: NA12877
 vcf: /data/NA12877.hard-filtered.vcf.gz

...
Channel
    samples.map { it.biosample_id }
    .set { sample_ids }

// channel for samplelist vcf input file processed outputs
  Channel
    .empty()
    sample_ids
    .join( count_variants.out )
    .join( bcftools_stats.out )
    .set { vcf_qc }


// aln can be either bam or cram format
// channel for samplelist input file type bam processed outputs
  Channel
    .empty()
    sample_ids
    .join( samtools_stats_bam.out.stats )
    ....
    .join( verifybamid2_bam.out.freemix, remainder: true )
    .set { ch_bam }

// channel for samplelist input file type cram processed outputs
  Channel
    .empty()
    sample_ids
    .join( samtools_stats_cram.out.stats )
    ....
    .join( verifybamid2_cram.out.freemix, remainder: true )
    .set { ch_cram }

...
// channel to mix the bam/cram process outputs and/or variants process outputs 
  ch_bam.mix(ch_cram) // .ifEmpty([]) The channel contain sample id, will not be fully empty even if the aln (bam/cram) input are not given 
    //.combine(vcf_qc,by:0)
    .join(vcf_qc, remainder: true)
    .map { file -> file - null } //.map { it.minus(null) }
    .view()
    //.flatten()
    //.map { sample, stats, insertsize, quality, wgs_coverage, freemix, count_variants, bcftools_stats -> [ sample, stats ?: [], insertsize ?: [], quality ?: [], wgs_coverage ?: [], freemix ?: [], count_variants ?: [], bcftools_stats ?: [] ] }
    .set { ga4gh_metrics_in }

  ga4gh_metrics( ga4gh_metrics_in )

Lists in the ga4gh_metrics_in...
[NA12878, ../NA12878.variant_counts.json, ../NA12878.pass.stats] // if input only `vcf` file

[NA12878, ../NA12878.stats, ../NA12878.insert_size_metrics.txt, ../NA12878.quality_yield_metrics.txt, ../NA12878_wgs_metrics.txt, ../NA12878.selfSM] // if input only `aln` file

[NA12878, ../NA12878.stats, ../NA12878.insert_size_metrics.txt, ../NA12878.quality_yield_metrics.txt, ../NA12878_wgs_metrics.txt, ../NA12878.selfSM, ../NA12878.variant_counts.json, ../NA12878.pass.stats] // if input both `aln` and `vcf` files

Using .map { file -> file - null } filtered the null in the list if the input contain only alignment (aln) or variants (vcf) files.
eg. only vcf input option
[NA12878, null, ../NA12878_1000genomes-dragen-3.7.6/work/../NA12878.variant_counts.json, ../NA12878_1000genomes-dragen-3.7.6/work/../NA12878.pass.stats]

process ga4gh_metrics
process ga4gh_metrics {

  tag { sample }

  input:
  ??????

  //tuple val(sample), path(stats), path(picard_insert_size), path(picard_quality), path(picard_wgs_coverage), path(verifybamid_freemix), path(count_variants), path(bcftools_stats) // both aln and vcf processed outputs

  //tuple val(sample), path(variantscounts), path(stats) // only vcf processed output 

  //tuple val(sample), path(stats), path(picard_insert_size), path(picard_quality), path(picard_wgs_coverage), path(verifybamid_freemix) // only aln processed output 


To my knowledge there is no way to put something like an if else in the input declaration (though see ternary operators). That said, you can create empty channels when a specific file type is not present, which stop input cardinality errors. Then you can put the if else statements in the script block to detect when a channel is empty and not run the associated commands.
If you don't like that idea, it might be worth going to the nextflow slack for more support.
